# How to bind views in Fragment using DataBindingUtil?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

In an activity can bind and access `myView` which is a subview in the layout like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   ActivityExampleBinding views = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_example);
   views.myView.doSomething();
}
```

How can I do that in a Fragment? I can return the inflated root view like this:

```
@Override
public @Nullable View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewDataBinding views = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_example, container,false);
    return views.getRoot();
}
```

But how can I access a subview in the layout?

Comment: Use `FragmentExampleBinding.inflate()`, which will return a `FragmentExampleBinding`. Then, you use `FragmentExampleBinding` much as you are presently using `ActivityExampleBinding`.

Comment: So I would not use `DataBindingUtil.inflate` but `FragmentExampleBinding.inflate`?

Comment: AFAIK, you're welcome to stick with `DataBindingUtil.inflate()`. Just change `views` to be a `FragmentExampleBinding`. Both `setContentView()` and `inflate()` have the same return type, according to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil).

Comment: Thanks, it works! I only stumbled upon `ExampleFragment_ViewBinding` and got confused by that, didn't see the `FragmentExampleBinding` class.

Comment: If you want to write an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is fine, if you want to stick with it — just change the `view` variable to be a `FragmentExampleBinding` (matching your `fragment_example` layout resource name).

Alternatively, use `FragmentExampleBinding.inflate()`, as you do not need to pass in the layout resource ID.

Comment: Since you're the Android expert in here, would you mind taking a look at this related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59231333/is-unbinding-necessary-when-using-databindingutil

Comment: @Manuel: Sorry, I don't know the answer. The fact that LeakCanary isn't complaining is a good sign, though.

Comment: Yes, I am not unbinding in a production app and I have not observed any significant change in OOM or other crashes, so I assume unbinding is not required. Thanks.